# No bottom arrow on Bootstrap Tool tip on table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use an Bootstrap tool tip in a bootstrap table. More or less it works as it should. But i can get it to show the small arrow at the bottom. I have no problems getting it to work outside an table.

```
<div class="imgtooltip displayInLineBlock" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="History">
<a class="breakDownListShowEquipLongText " href="#" data-notificationid="5000">
        <img class="vcenter marginTopMinus2 displayInLineBlock" src="/api/Icon/GetIcon/?size=15&amp;iconkeyname=MMS_ViewLog" alt="MMS"></a></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'top',
});
```

```css
.cart {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart"> 
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="add to cart">
        <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4WwQ/767/)

**Update:**

You can change placement to top,bottom,right,left